# How to alter column in varchar datatype to timestamp? The data in the column are in the format 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, timestamp, amazon-redshift, alter

Given the below sample data, what will be the alter column clause in Redshift to change it to timestamp? currently it is in varchar

| timestamp |
| --- |
| 2021-11-23T13:39:54+00:00 |
| 2021-11-23T14:16:25+00:00 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cast(column_name as timestamp)
```

You can read about it here:

[https://devdocs.io/postgresql~9.4/sql-expressions#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS](https://devdocs.io/postgresql%7E9.4/sql-expressions#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)